# Help Me to Identify Relay Pins of this Circuit Diagram

Tags: relay

This is the circuit diagram that have a Relay Which I need to identify terminals.

[image]

By searching on Internet I guess this is how it connected.

[image]

My question is, The Way I found match the circuit Diagram?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified which label corresponds to which pin in the schematic.

Comment: So many words for "yes" 